# Floor division // vs int() rounded off

Tags: python, floating-point, int, rounding, floor-division

I am a new user to Python 3.6.0. I am trying to divide 2 numbers that produces a big output. However, using

```
return ans1 // ans2
```

produces 55347740058143507128 while using

```
return int(ans1 / ans2)
```

produces 55347740058143506432.

Which is more accurate and why is that so?

Comment: You need to specify the language that you are using.

Comment: @zneak Oh thanks. Im a noob.

Comment: Yeah! No problem. Can you clarify which version of Python you're using, as well? Finally, could you run `repr(ans1)` and `repr(ans2)` and post the result?

Comment: @zneak Ok. I am using 3.6.0. I have printed repr(ans1) as 45159067006671175434518243598614826795313039459718126370816000000000 and repr(ans2) as 815915283247897734345611269596115894272000000000.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  Please look at the [guide to asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Next time, be sure to tag your question with the language - most people look for questions with tags, so most of your audience will not see this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first one is more accurate since it gives the exact integer result.

The second represents the intermediate result as a float. Floats have limited resolution ([53 bits of mantissa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)) whereas the result needs 66 bits to be represented exactly. This results in a loss of accuracy.

If we looks at the hex representation of both results:

```
>>> hex(55347740058143507128)
'0x3001aac56864d42b8L'
>>> hex(55347740058143506432)
'0x3001aac56864d4000L'
```

we can see that the least-significant bits of the result that didn't fit in a 53-bit mantissa all got set to zero.

One way to see the rounding directly, without any complications brought about by division is:

```
>>> int(float(55347740058143507128))
55347740058143506432L
```

Answer (score 3):

The flooring integer division is more accurate, in that sense.

The problem with this construction `int(ans1 / ans2)`, is that the result is temporarily a float (before, obviously, converting it to an integer), introducing rounding to the nearest float (the amount of rounding depends on the magnitude of the number). This can even be seen by just trying to round-trip that value through a float:

```
print(int(float(55347740058143507128)))
```

Which prints `55347740058143506432`. So, because plain `/` results in a float, that limits its accuracy.